# how to match $ in javascript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am using other people's code to build a front end filter to generate query into database. I need to build the operations like:

```
var operations = {
    "$and" : "and",
    "$or"  : "or",
    "$eq": "equal to ( = )",
    "$ne": "not equal ( != )",
    "$gt": "greater than ( > )",
    "$lt": "less than ( < )",
    "$gte": "gerater than or equal to ( >= )",
    "$lte": "less than or equal to ( <= )"
}
```

However, when the key with "$", it doesn't show with ng-options, but when it will show correctly without "$". I am thinking, probably it's affected by RegExp, so I found there are two parts of code including RegExp: 
first:

```
var currIndexTemp = query.expression ? query.expression.match(/[^A-Za-z()]/g) : 0;
```

Second:

```
var expArray = expression.split(/((?:\(|\)|[A-Z]+|\d+))/g);
```

I am not familiar with RegExp, anyone can help to diagnose the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify what your actual goal is? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are those regex's part of Angular?  If so, modifying them is likely an unwise choice.  IMO, this is an example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Sorry, everybody, I think I didn't explain very clearly. right now I fixed this problem by using other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dollar sign is a special control character that cannot be matched literally (you need to escape it).

To match, say `$eq` you can use the regex:

```
/\$eq/
 ^ escape $
```

I hope this helps you out, because I don't really get the regex you've written. They do something different altogether that isn't explained in your question. Maybe ask differently what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help. I think I didn't express this question very clearly, right now, I have figured out another way to solve this issue.